# spock: verifying interaction using closures as a parameters

Tags: testing, groovy, jvm, spock

i want to write parameterized test that uses `where:` to verify if a method `x` was called. and i want to pass `x` as a parameter. something like

```
when:
someService.request(input)
then:
1 * (closure.call(otherService))
where
input | closure
1     | {OtherService service -> service.method1(2, 3)}
2     | {OtherService service -> service.method2(4, 5, 6)}
```

but i got an error:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * (closure.call(otherService))   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * otherService.deleteUserMessage(2,3)
```

is what i want to do possible?

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to achieve can be easily done by using interaction based tests instead of trying to complicate the testing process and making it cumbersome to comprehend:

```
when:
someService.request(1)

then:
1 * service.method1(2, 3)

when:
someService.request(2)

then:
1 * service.method1(4, 5, 6)
```

Are you expecting more interactions than those two above?

Comment: this doesn't isolate calls :(

Comment: That is as good as writing a separate test for each case. Keeps the test clear, ease to understand.

Comment: when request() changes state of the underlying objects, those changes may affect the next request() call. e.g. when user have limited number of request available

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Spock is interpreting the closure as a mocked interaction, which it isn't. I see what you *want* to do, by having the closure return the mocked service's interaction, but that isn't how it is going to play out.

You could consider simplifying your test, as dmahapatro mentioned, or you could explore using the built in [spock](https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html) `interaction` closure. You'd have to rethink how you design your test, but you could offload the interactions to other, resuable method(s) that can create interactions for you as well.

Comment: i would appreciate any pseudo-code sample of using `interaction` clusure and 'offloading interactions'